# how to "destring" an object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

i have an array which looks like this:

```
[ 
"[-33.85812364015231, 151.19984484776273]", 
"[-33.85812364015231, 151.19984484776273]", 
"[-33.87137985320215, 151.19263084032974]"
]
```

how do i get the objects out of their strings. Parsing them into floats removed the second value in the object. Trying to replace( ' " ', " ") the speech marks doesn't work.

thanks

Comment: Use `JSON.parse()`

Comment: ^ `strings.map(string => JSON.parse(string))` to be exact. If you only need the first value use `JSON.parse(string)[0]`  instead.

Answer (score 4):

You have an array of JSON strings.

To get an array of arrays of numbers, use

```
const parsedArr = arr.map(JSON.parse);
```

and then `parsedArray[someNum]` will give you a coordinate array of numbers, like `[-33.85812364015231, 151.19984484776273]`.

Answer (score 1):

this way :
without unnecessarily recreating a new array *(as does the `array.map()` method )*

```js
const myArray = 
  [ "[-33.85812364015231, 151.19984484776273]"
  , "[-33.85812364015231, 151.19984484776273]" 
  , "[-33.87137985320215, 151.19263084032974]"
  ]
  
myArray.forEach((row,i,Arr) =>  Arr[i] = JSON.parse(row) )

console.log( myArray )
```